# СИ | Поиск повторяющихся слов в массиве

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void mindl(char* s2) {
    char *s3[1000];

    int i = 0;
    int por = 0;
    char* povtor[1];
    char* p;
    p = strtok(s2, " ");
    while (p != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(p);
        s3[i] = malloc(len + 1);
        if (s3[i] == NULL) { perror("Out of memory"); exit(-1); }
        strcpy(s3[i], p);
        i++;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    //тут подсчёт повторяющихся слов 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char s1[1000];
    int n;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    printf("Введите количетсво строк: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Введите строку: ");
        gets(s1);
        mindl(s1);
    }

}
```

Как посчитать количество повторяющихся слов? Никак не могу придумать алгоритм.

Comment: Отсортируйте список слов, далее подсчёт дубликатов делается за один проход, т. к. сравнивать надо только соседние.

Comment: Либо используйте словарь, где ключ - слово, значение - количество повторов

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю, может, кто-то может написать как надо?